# calling RankToPosition() and _onMoveToPositionClicked

Tags: rally, rank, bulk, user-stories

I have a situation where i'd like to enter a "3" into a textbox on a user story grid, call something like RankToPosition(3) to move that user story row to position 3 in the current rank. Within the same grid, the idea is to have a textbox on each row, so the row beneath may have a 4 in there, and when i click SUBMIT, the entire table would be processed by using the numbers in the row textbox and calling RankToPosition(#). This is like the Netflix queue. There have been similar questions on here, but my thought is to just call the underlying method alluded to here as "_onMoveToPositionClicked":

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/source/MoveToPositionMenuItem.html#Rally-ui-menu-item-MoveToPositionMenuItem-cfg-rankRecordHelper

If i could iterate through the table grid, store initial rank values (i realize they're not just integers), and pick the new text values up, run code to call the _onMoveToPositionClicked beneath the scenes, it may accomplish a bulk rank grid for when users have 200+ items to manage, for instance.

Any insight you have for just calling this in custom code would be helpful. Any solution for representing this functionality would be appreciated. I am currently using Rally 2.0rc3.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to upgrade to a newer version of the App SDK?  2.0rc3 is a very old pre-release.  The latest is 2.1: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/

In any case, the way ranking is performed is relative to another object via the rankAbove or rankBelow parameters.  So given the record you want to rerank:

```
record.save({
    params: {
        rankAbove: '/hierarchicalrequirement/12345'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Kyle. We'll look into using that method.